# run same airflow DAG in parallel

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm using Airflow 2.0.2.
I want to run the same DAG in parallel (at least 2, max 4 at the same time).

I have wrapper DAG A to call DAG B. I set max_active_run for DAG B to 4. When I trigger DAG A, it shows 2 tasks (triggering same DAG B) are running. but for DAG B, only 1 instance running.

In DAG A:

```
for i in list:
    run_task=TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='trigger_' + i,                                                    
                                   trigger_dag_id='dag_b',
                                   execution_date='{{ ts }}',
                                   conf={"run_job": i},
                                   reset_dag_run=True,
                                   wait_for_completion=True,
                                   poke_interval=60
                                   )
```

in DAB B:

```
with DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID, default_args=dflt_args,
          description='blah blah blah',
          schedule_interval=None,
          tags = tags,
          catchup=False,
          concurrency=4,
          max_active_runs=4
        ) as dag:
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQLite. Check your airflow.cfg It should be using SequentialExecutor. If so, change it to LocalExecutor and execute dag A

Comment: actually, If I use 2 different DAGs to trigger this DAG B about the same time(few seconds in between the triggers), I see 2 instances of DAG B running. But if I trigger it in the loop (as shown above), only one runs.

Comment: what is the executor on yout cfg file ?

Comment: I figured it out. The run_id is using the execution_date by default. I need to add a few seconds or minutes in each iteration to differentiate the date/time (which is the run_id)